# What size aws ec2 to install dlib?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, opencv, amazon-ec2, dlib

I'm trying to boot up an ubuntu ec2 instance and I need dlib installed. I am trying to use the command `pip install dlib` and the installation is breaking.

I'm using a Ubuntu deep learning AMI because it has cv2 and other package I need already installed. I started with a p2.large but moved to a p2.xlarge because this post recommended getting more RAM to install dlib.

[How to install pip2 on kali?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66028181/how-to-install-pip2-on-kali)

However, this did not work.

Any ideas?

Here's the error message:

```
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.21.1.tar.gz (3.6 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1nd52hmz/dlib_d4fe1d2320054b38a6c0e81d4dd21a8a/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1nd52hmz/dlib_d4fe1d2320054b38a6c0e81d4dd21a8a/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-dj_f226q
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-1nd52hmz/dlib_d4fe1d2320054b38a6c0e81d4dd21a8a/
  Complete output (537 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'tools/python/dlib/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.6.10 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan  7 2020, 21:14:29)
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake /tmp/pip-install-1nd52hmz/dlib_d4fe1d2320054b38a6c0e81d4dd21a8a/tools/python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/tmp/pip-install-1nd52hmz/dlib_d4fe1d2320054b38a6c0e81d4dd21a8a/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/bin/python -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release'
  -- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
  -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working C compiler: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc - skipped
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++ - skipped
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  -- Found PythonInterp: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/bin/python (found version "3.6.10")
  -- Found PythonLibs: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/libpython3.6m.so
  -- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG
  -- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG - Success
  -- pybind11 v2.2.4
  -- Using CMake version: 3.18.4
  -- Compiling dlib version: 19.21.1
  -- SSE4 instructions can be executed by the host processor.
  -- AVX instructions can be executed by the host processor.
  -- Enabling AVX instructions
  -- Looking for pthread.h
  -- Looking for pthread.h - found
  -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
  -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
  -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
  -- Found Threads: TRUE
  -- Could NOT find X11 (missing: X11_X11_LIB)
   *****************************************************************************
   *** DLIB GUI SUPPORT DISABLED BECAUSE X11 DEVELOPMENT LIBRARIES NOT FOUND ***
   *** Make sure libx11-dev is installed if you want GUI support.            ***
   *** On Ubuntu run: sudo apt-get install libx11-dev                        ***
   *****************************************************************************
  -- Found system copy of libpng: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/libpng.so;/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/libz.so
  -- Found system copy of libjpeg: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/libjpeg.so
  -- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
  -- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
  -- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1")
  -- Checking for module 'cblas'
  --   No package 'cblas' found
  -- Checking for module 'lapack'
  --   Found lapack, version 3.10.3
  -- Looking for cblas_ddot
  -- Looking for cblas_ddot - not found
  -- Looking for sys/types.h
  -- Looking for sys/types.h - found
  -- Looking for stdint.h
  -- Looking for stdint.h - found
  -- Looking for stddef.h
  -- Looking for stddef.h - found
  -- Check size of void*
  -- Check size of void* - done
  -- Found Intel MKL BLAS/LAPACK library
  -- Looking for sgesv
  -- Looking for sgesv - found
  -- Looking for sgesv_
  -- Looking for sgesv_ - found
  -- Found CUDA: /usr/local/cuda-10.1 (found suitable version "10.1", minimum required is "7.5")
  -- Looking for cuDNN install...
  -- Found cuDNN: /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so
  -- Building a CUDA test project to see if your compiler is compatible with CUDA...
  -- Building a cuDNN test project to check if you have the right version of cuDNN installed...
  -- Enabling CUDA support for dlib.  DLIB WILL USE CUDA
  -- C++11 activated.
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: /tmp/pip-install-1nd52hmz/dlib_d4fe1d2320054b38a6c0e81d4dd21a8a/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  Invoking CMake build: 'cmake --build . --config Release -- -j32'
  [  1%] Building NVCC (Device) object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/cuda/dlib_generated_cusolver_dlibapi.cu.o
  [  2%] Building NVCC (Device) object dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/cuda/dlib_generated_cuda_dlib.cu.o
  /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/include/c++/7.3.0/type_traits(177): error: "conjunction_v" is not a function or static data member

  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1nd52hmz/dlib_d4fe1d2320054b38a6c0e81d4dd21a8a/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1nd52hmz/dlib_d4fe1d2320054b38a6c0e81d4dd21a8a/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-5n01zfw0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/include/python3.6m/dlib
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-1nd52hmz/dlib_d4fe1d2320054b38a6c0e81d4dd21a8a/
    Complete output (539 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'tools/python/dlib/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.6.10 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan  7 2020, 21:14:29)
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake /tmp/pip-install-1nd52hmz/dlib_d4fe1d2320054b38a6c0e81d4dd21a8a/tools/python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/tmp/pip-install-1nd52hmz/dlib_d4fe1d2320054b38a6c0e81d4dd21a8a/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/bin/python -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release'
    -- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
    -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working C compiler: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc - skipped
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++ - skipped
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Found PythonInterp: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/bin/python (found version "3.6.10")
    -- Found PythonLibs: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/libpython3.6m.so
    -- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG
    -- Performing Test HAS_CPP14_FLAG - Success
    -- pybind11 v2.2.4
    -- Using CMake version: 3.18.4
    -- Compiling dlib version: 19.21.1
    -- SSE4 instructions can be executed by the host processor.
    -- AVX instructions can be executed by the host processor.
    -- Enabling AVX instructions
    -- Looking for pthread.h
    -- Looking for pthread.h - found
    -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
    -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
    -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
    -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
    -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
    -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
    -- Found Threads: TRUE
    -- Could NOT find X11 (missing: X11_X11_LIB)
     *****************************************************************************
     *** DLIB GUI SUPPORT DISABLED BECAUSE X11 DEVELOPMENT LIBRARIES NOT FOUND ***
     *** Make sure libx11-dev is installed if you want GUI support.            ***
     *** On Ubuntu run: sudo apt-get install libx11-dev                        ***
     *****************************************************************************

    Error limit reached.
    100 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00017e17_00000000-6_cusolver_dlibapi.cpp1.ii".
    Compilation terminated.
    CMake Error at dlib_generated_cusolver_dlibapi.cu.o.Release.cmake:280 (message):
      Error generating file
      /tmp/pip-install-1nd52hmz/dlib_d4fe1d2320054b38a6c0e81d4dd21a8a/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/cuda/./dlib_generated_cusolver_dlibapi.cu.o
    
    
    dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/build.make:89: recipe for target 'dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/cuda/dlib_generated_cusolver_dlibapi.cu.o' failed
    make[2]: *** [dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/cuda/dlib_generated_cusolver_dlibapi.cu.o] Error 1
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:162: recipe for target 'dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/all' failed
    make[1]: *** [dlib_build/CMakeFiles/dlib.dir/all] Error 2
    Makefile:102: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-1nd52hmz/dlib_d4fe1d2320054b38a6c0e81d4dd21a8a/setup.py", line 262, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-1nd52hmz/dlib_d4fe1d2320054b38a6c0e81d4dd21a8a/setup.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-1nd52hmz/dlib_d4fe1d2320054b38a6c0e81d4dd21a8a/setup.py", line 175, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_build, cwd=build_folder)
      File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '-j32']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1nd52hmz/dlib_d4fe1d2320054b38a6c0e81d4dd21a8a/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1nd52hmz/dlib_d4fe1d2320054b38a6c0e81d4dd21a8a/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-5n01zfw0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/include/python3.6m/dlib Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.3.3; however, version 21.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: The error message suggests `sudo apt-get install libx11-dev`. Did you try that?

Comment: @connor449 - Which base AMI you are using? Because, this command works smoothly on `Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu 16.04) Version 38.0 (ami-0949532e81c9eab21)`

Comment: @amitd I am using the Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu 16.04) like you. `pip install dlib` works for you? What is the instance type?

Comment: @connor449 - I used `p2.xlarge` with AMI `ami-0949532e81c9eab21` and without any custom config or changes, before installing `dlib`

Comment: @amitd How do I find this ami? When I search by the ami-id, I get no results. When I search with the full title you provided a few comments back, I get a custom ami by a company `Bansir`. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: @amitd do you think this will work? `Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu 16.04) Version 39.0 - ami-06658344d912d040b` . I ask just because its a hassle and takes a while to configure, test, and terminate if it fails. Thanks.

Comment: The above ami worked. Thanks @amitd

Comment: @connor449 - Thank you for confirmation, I added it as one of the possible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using following combination is one of the possible option;

Amazon Machine Image (a.k.a. ami) = `ami-0949532e81c9eab21` (i.e. Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu 16.04) Version 38.0)

AWS EC2 Instance Type = `p2.xlarge`